# The Window of CLion/NetBeans freezes as soon as I click any button

Tags: freeze, netbeans, clion

When installing clion, when I do `./bin/clion.sh`, a window for installation would appear, but as soon as I click `continue` button the window freezes, but then I still can use other sofwares.

For NetBeans, after successful installation, everytime I try to use it, it would freeze when I click any button on the window, but then I can still use other softwares.

Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem with you, and i find the problem is caused by the sogoupinyin input method. You can use other input methods to avoid this problem.
Or you can choose to install ubuntu kylin version of sogou input method, will not meet this problem.